# Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker do not show calendar, even with everything loaded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

All right so i installed the Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker from Eonasdan and i'm having a pretty big issue making it work, i used bower to install so i'm guessing that's the problem..

after my `</body>` i have:

```
<!--Datepicker-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

before my `</head>` i have:

and yes i'm loading the jquery and the bootstrap like the [installation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/) guide:

(before `</head>`)

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

(after `</body>`)

```
<!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

on the html i have:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

so what have i done wrong?

Comment: Did you check the error log? Most of the time the message will indicate something goes wrong (and where).

Comment: did you add bootstrap.js ? if not also it should work ! are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: Yes, i checked the error log, and it's clean like white paper, i also used console.log() on .js files, no return or error, and i also loaded bootstrap, also from bower.